# Should i check amount sent in PayPal IPN

Tags: paypal

This may sound odd, but should I check if the amount sent via IPN is correct?

In my IPN listeneer, I send the post values back to Paypal to vertify them, so I assume all values are the same as on PayPal. (Amount paid etc, item name, etc.)

And the next thing is, people can't find my IPN URL, because I generate an link and redirect them to it, which is encrypted.

The reason I'm asking if I dont have to check the amount is because i run my site with coupons, and checking if the amount is correct, would be hard.
And also, my IPN URL is dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason people check the amount is to make sure somebody didn't copy your HTML button code, change the amount of the product, and then submit a payment using that adjusted code.  This would go through PayPal and your IPN would indeed come from them, so it would verify, but if somebody changed the amount like that and you shipped the product without realizing it that could be a bad deal.

This isn't required if you're using hosted buttons or encrypted buttons.  That stuff gets hidden so people can't do that.  Same goes with API requests.  It's really only a potential problem if you're using standard HTML buttons or checkout code that isn't hidden in any way.